# Parsing http request in elixir

Tags: parsing

I have created a websocket connection with cowboy_Websocket handler.
When I am recieving a http request from the front end, I am not able to parse that http request in elixir code.
Can anyone suggest any code for parsing an http request over a cowboy websocket in elixir.

Answer (score 0):

Just leaving [a blog article](https://medium.com/@loganbbres/elixir-websocket-chat-example-c72986ab5778) here, in case anyone needs it. Good example in case you don't want to use the Phoenix Sockets.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.